# Let X be a metrizable TVS of infinite dimension. Show that there exists a discontinuous linear functional on X.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, linear-transformations, topological-vector-spaces

The exercise had one hint: Use an algebraic basis of $X$ and Problem 22. And  the Problem 22: Let $X$ be a metrizable TVS and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of elements of $X$. Show that there exists a sequence of strictly positive numbers $(λ_n)$ such that $λ_n x_n \rightarrow 0_X$.

And the Problem 22 had one hint too: Let ρ be a metric generating the topology on X. Show and then use that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow 0+} \rho(0_X, tx) = 0$ for each $x \in X$.

Comment: Which book is this exercise from?

Comment: I dont know! Is on a list that I found on the internet, www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~kalenda/data/fa116e-pr5.pdf, for this university https://www.mff.cuni.cz/cs/matematicka-sekce/o-sekci.

Comment: Start with $x_n$ a set of linearly independent vectors. Define $f(\sum_n a_n x_n):= \sum_n \frac{a_n}{\lambda_n}$ where $\lambda_n$ is as in your exercise 22, this is linear on the span of the $x_n$. Is it continuous? can you extend this functional to all of $X$? Will it the extension be continuous on $X$?

Comment: @s.harp I think I understood! It will not be continuous and its extension is also not. But since X is not standardized, it is only metrizable, I cannot guarantee the extension using Hahn-Banach right away. can I get a function that limits $ f $ to use H. B.?

Comment: You don't need H.-B. here. Let $\Xi$ be an (algebraic) basis of $X$, $(x_n)$ be a sequence of distinct elements of $\Xi$, $\lambda_n$ as above, and define $f(x)$ for $x\in\Xi$ (which automatically defines $f$ on the whole of $X$) by $f(x)=1/\lambda_n$ if $x=x_n$ for some $n$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.